# How to change the face of only a text segment in org-agenda?

Tags: org-agenda, faces, text-properties

I am trying to do this on my `org-agenda`. In the example below, I want that the text `[MY PROJECT]` has a distinct face (`nano-strong`, for example) than the next line `NEXT My next task`.

If I have a subtree like this,

```
* MY PROJECT :my-tag:
** NEXT My next task
```

I would like a formatted view in the org-agenda like this

```
**[MY PROJECT]**
↳ NEXT My next task    :my-tag:
```

**(the double asterisks are just to emphasize that I want a bold font for this part)**

I tried using a `propertize` with a `concat` to create the breadcrumb.  Then using `org-agenda-prefix-format` to put the text where I want.

The problem is the `propertize` part isn't respected for `org-agenda`. So the face aren't changed at all.

This is my best try so far,

```
(defun my/org-agenda-format-breadcrumbs ()
  ""
  (let ((breadcrumb (org-format-outline-path (cdr (org-get-outline-path)))))
    (if (string-empty-p breadcrumb)
        (concat " ")
      (concat "[" (propertize breadcrumb 'face 'nano-strong) "]\n   ↳"))))

(setq org-agenda-prefix-format '((agenda . " %i %s")
                                 (todo   . "%i %-12:c")
                                 (tags   . "%(my/org-agenda-format-breadcrumbs)")
                                 (search . "%i %-12:c")))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know if you are doing anything wrong, but even if it is all correct, it's not going to work. The prefix format string is calculated early in `org-agenda-list`, which goes on to apply a *ton* of properties on the resulting entries. Generate an agenda and do `C-u C-x =` at the beginning of the line you are interested in: you'll see 30-40 properties on it. Moreover, these properties are *essential* to the workings of the agenda. Anything you do is almost guaranteed to be overwritten (one way to get around that is to use `org-agenda-finalize-hook`) but even if you succeed, you are...

Comment: ...  likely to break agenda operations.

Comment: Well, I don't know: I'm not sure the `face` property is used anywhere else (but you should check), so you may be able to change just that in a function that's called by `org-agenda-finalize-hook`.